# XSL to Text, equivilant of 'fmt'

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm processing an XML document which has `<paragraph>` tags which contain text into a plain-text file. Sometimes the lines are broken in odd places, and sometimes they are too long. I have a template for paragraphs that simply runs the apply-template action and appends a couple of newlines.

Is there a way to reformat the text() in the paragraph similar to the unix 'fmt' command (which rewraps the stream of text to a normalized width) *after* the apply-templates has a chance to handle other tags within the paragraph (such as bold, em, etc).

Also, is there a way for each reformatted line to be indented, as you would normally do in a block quote in a plain-text document?

Comment: Don't expect many people to know what "unix 'fmt' " does. Please, provide a complete example of a (small) XML document, the exact desired output and the rules that the transformation should fulfill.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an easy XSLT 1.0 solution that uses the FXSL template `str-split-to-lines`.

Comment: So, @JeffG, Was my answer useful?

Comment: XSLT isn't the best tool for manipulating strings in this way. You're probably better off looking into using extension functions if you really need to do this within the transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One easy solution is to use the `str-split-to-lines` template from [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net) like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:str-split2lines-func="f:str-split2lines-func"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f ext str-split2lines-func"
>


   <xsl:import href="dvc-str-foldl.xsl"/>

   <str-split2lines-func:str-split2lines-func/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-lines">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/*"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pLineLength" select="50"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" select="' &#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="str-split-to-lines">
      <xsl:param name="pStr"/>
      <xsl:param name="pLineLength" select="60"/>
      <xsl:param name="pDelimiters" select="' &#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vsplit2linesFun"
                    select="document('')/*/str-split2lines-func:*[1]"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vrtfParams">
       <delimiters><xsl:value-of select="$pDelimiters"/></delimiters>
       <lineLength><xsl:copy-of select="$pLineLength"/></lineLength>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="vResult">
          <xsl:call-template name="dvc-str-foldl">
            <xsl:with-param name="pFunc" select="$vsplit2linesFun"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="$pStr"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="ext:node-set($vrtfParams)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($vResult)/line">
        <xsl:for-each select="word">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="str-split2lines-func:*" mode="f:FXSL">
      <xsl:param name="arg1" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="arg2"/>

      <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/*[position() &lt; 3]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/line[position() != last()]"/>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($arg1/*[1], $arg2)">
          <xsl:if test="string($arg1/word)">
             <xsl:call-template name="fillLine">
               <xsl:with-param name="pLine" select="$arg1/line[last()]"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pWord" select="$arg1/word"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pLineLength" select="$arg1/*[2]"/>
             </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/line[last()]"/>
          <word><xsl:value-of select="concat($arg1/word, $arg2)"/></word>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

      <!-- Test if the new word fits into the last line -->
    <xsl:template name="fillLine">
      <xsl:param name="pLine" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="pWord" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="pLineLength" />

      <xsl:variable name="vnWordsInLine" select="count($pLine/word)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vLineLength" 
       select="string-length($pLine) + $vnWordsInLine"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($vLineLength + string-length($pWord) 
                           > 
                            $pLineLength)">
          <line>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pLine/*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pWord"/>
          </line>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$pLine"/>
          <line>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pWord"/>
          </line>
          <word/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on an XML document like this one**:

```
<text>
Dec. 13 — As always for a presidential inaugural, security and surveillance were
extremely tight in Washington, DC, last January. But as George W. Bush prepared to
take the oath of office, security planners installed an extra layer of protection: a
prototype software system to detect a biological attack. The U.S. Department of
Defense, together with regional health and emergency-planning agencies, distributed
a special patient-query sheet to military clinics, civilian hospitals and even aid
stations along the parade route and at the inaugural balls. Software quickly
analyzed complaints of seven key symptoms — from rashes to sore throats — for
patterns that might indicate the early stages of a bio-attack. There was a brief
scare: the system noticed a surge in flulike symptoms at military clinics.
Thankfully, tests confirmed it was just that — the flu.
</text>
```

**The wanted output (words wrapped in lines with maximum width of 50) is produced**:

```
Dec. 13 — As always for a presidential inaugural, 
security and surveillance were extremely tight in 
Washington, DC, last January. But as George W. 
Bush prepared to take the oath of office, security 
planners installed an extra layer of protection: a 
prototype software system to detect a biological 
attack. The U.S. Department of Defense, together 
with regional health and emergency-planning 
agencies, distributed a special patient-query 
sheet to military clinics, civilian hospitals and 
even aid stations along the parade route and at 
the inaugural balls. Software quickly analyzed 
complaints of seven key symptoms — from rashes to 
sore throats — for patterns that might indicate 
the early stages of a bio-attack. There was a 
brief scare: the system noticed a surge in flulike 
symptoms at military clinics. Thankfully, tests 
confirmed it was just that — the flu.
```